# I can not parse a json string with nested elements into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is the top part the JSON String, I can supply the full string, but it is rather large.

```
{
    "InspectionResultAggregate": {
        "ValuationAggregate": {
            "MainStreetValuation": {
                "ValuationIdentifier": {
                    "RecordId": 2393438,
                    "PolicyNumber": "1143822",
                    "VersionId": 7005058
                },
                "RecordType": "INS",
                "DataSource": "FIT",
                "PropertyAddress": {
                    "Address1": "9-11 EDGEWOOD AVENUE ",
                    "Address2": " ",
                    "City": "ATTLEBORO",
                    "StateOrProvince": "MA",
                    "ZipOrPostalCode": "02703"
                },
                "OwnerUser": "UnknownUser",
                "AssignedByUser": "PrimeVal_FIT",
                "CreateDate": "2014-04-07T12:04:26.22",
                "CreateUser": "PrimeVal_FIT",
                "UpdateDate": "2014-04-18T12:27:00.4390372-07:00",
                "UpdateStatusDate": "2014-04-07T12:04:25.433",
                "UpdateUser": "PrimeVal_FIT",
                "InsuredCustomer": {
                    "FullName": "CAROL AND TREVOR CLARKE ",
                    "SecondFullName": " ",
                    "MailingAddressSameAsPropertyAddress": true,
                    "MailingAddress": {
                        "Address1": "",
                        "Address2": "",
                        "City": ""
                    }
                }
```

This is the Code:
No matter what I try, I can not assign the policynumber to var p.

```
// CALCULATE VALUE
$('#calculate').click(function () {
    $('#general_message').text('Calculating...').fadeIn(1);
    dataString = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_submit_soap_request.php",
        data: dataString,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#general_message').text('Calculation Finished!').fadeOut(3000);
            var p = data.InspectionResultAggregate.ValuationAggregate.MainStreetValuation.ValuationIdentifier.PolicyNumber;
            $('#policy').text(p);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

Comment: A sample of the JSON string is fine, but try to make sure it's valid. As is, it's missing 4 `}`. But, have you tried adding an `error` handler to the `$.ajax()` request and inspected the `errorThrown`?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you tried logging `data` to the console and seeing if it looks like you expect it to?

Comment: Fix your JSON Structure. you can use [this online tool](http://json.parser.online.fr/) very helpfull.

Comment: The first sentence reads that the JSON being supplied is the top part of the object, not the full object.  It would be helpful if you posted the entire object, or even better, use an online tool to verify it's a legitimate JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to set the dat type with `datatype`, when it should be `dataType`

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: but the default value is "educated guess" which will usually esult in JSON anyways for a json string

Comment: @RuneFS Though, the educated guess is based on the responding `Content-Type`, which may not be `application/json` or similar for auto-parsing.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yes yes im just sying it's not evident from the context that the dataType would cause ny problem (though specifying it like this is of course without meaning)

Comment: Musa, thank you I can't tell you how long I looked at the code and did not see the typo! Thanks everyone else for the input.